# KIF integration with Xcode using Cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods, kif, kif-framework

I am trying to integrate KIF with Xcode using cocoapods. When i try to build the workspace, i face the following issue.

[image]

[image]

Its searching for the Pods-Framework shell script under the applications Xcode project but the shell script is present under the pods Xcode project.I tried changing the path but it gets replaced automatically when i build it. Can anyone provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have add KIF.Framework in your normal target . Please add these frameworks in new unit test case target created by you.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have installed KIF framework for one of my projects. I have followed the below steps,

1. Created a project included with UnitTests and UITests.
2. Added Cocoapod to the project and added these dependencies

> pod 'KIF', '~> 3.2.0'
>       pod 'Specta', '~> 1.0.2'

3. And installed the cocoa pod to the iOS project.
4. Add a new test case file called "UITests" inherited from "KIFTestCase".
5. Import "#import  #import " classes to the class.
6. Write the test cases in "beforeAll" functions.

> Eg:    [tester enterText:@"user@example.com"
>   intoViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"UsernameTF"];

I didn't configure anything in Build Settings. But,am able to execute the test cases. Thanks.